# Are clang and llvm no longer maintained in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, llvm, clang

I cannot find binaries for clang or llvm using cygwin's setup.exe. Are they no longer maintained?

Answer (score 1):

llvm/clang is still maintained but currently available only for x86; it has yet to be ported to x86-64.